# Share video to youtube with ShareKit on iOS7

Tags: ios7, youtube, cocoapods, sharekit

I want to implement "sharing" on iOS 7 to share video file to facebook and youtube (the others are options). Spending lots of time to survey and try, I found UIActivityViewController can not share to youtube in default, and the iPhone users must set app login information to make the app icon appear in the view. Then, I found ShareKit ( https://github.com/ShareKit/ ) may reach my goal. I installed ShareKit via cocoapods (ref https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-ShareKit ), and found the youtube portion was not installed. The 2 files in https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/tree/master/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/YouTube do not exist if install via cocoapods. If I add the 2 files into pod project , the build will fail. How could I make the youtube sharing work? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit ShareKit.podspec. It is impossible (or at least it was last time I tried) to use  YouTube and Google+ at the same time. See the comments on the bottom of the pod spec file for more info.